# Oracle 10g installation in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, oracle10g

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate. I tried to install Oracle 10g but I am getting error message like below.

I am getting this error when I run the Oracle 10g setup file.

> "Error in writing to directory C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local|Temp. Oracle
>   Universal Installer needs you to have permission in this area to
>   install. Installation cannot continue. Please make sure that TEMP is
>   set to a valid writable directory"

After getting this I changed TEMP directory to another LOCAL DRIVE. The permission for the user is also seems ok for me.

Some times I am getting error like 
`"Error in writing to directory C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Tem\ Please ensure that this directory is writable and has atleast 45 MB of disk space. Installation cannot continue."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable any antivirus prior to clicking the setup file. This resolved my issue at least.